# R: quote any text or expression in R

Tags: string, r, quote

I am facing an apparently easy problem in R. 
That is to make a function (say "foo") to quote (i.e., make a string) from a line of "code". 
This is the example:

```
 foo( SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 100 )
```

The result must be:

```
"SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 100"
```

which is quoted (it is a string), without evaluation. That must work for any thing, like:

```
foo( 1234 ERE 34e3 & )
```

has to give:

```
"1234 ERE 34e3 &"

foo( x = 33 + 34 )
```

has to give:

```
"x = 33 + 34"
```

I am sure i miss something, but i really can not find a solution to this simple problem.

#### NEW EDIT :

We had many comments about the question and possible answers, very useful (see below), but none got the proper answer.

To clarify, i am ONLY interested on a general solution to the question I make. 
So I look to know if *there is a function* that can do what i say above, i.e. : 
**quote ANY code/text**,
*INDEPENDENTLY* of the specific context for what the function will be used.

Seems the answer is not easy or that is impossible. 
We can still try to see if we get a clever idea.
Thank you !

Comment: Can you provide some context on when this would actually come up?

Comment: Why can't you just wrap the expression in quotes and dispense with the function?

Comment: The context is to make a function that will take a SQL code-line, make it a string and evaluate it using sqldf. To manually put quotes in front and end of each piece, and name it, etc, gets too complicated. Also, i will use this function for other tasks.

Comment: You write "take a SQL code-line" - can you replace the word "take" with the name of the function you use (or otherwise more explicitly clarify "taking")? Also, where do you take the SQL statement from?

Comment: The SQL statment is taken from R the file i am working in. This file has for example the text: SELECT * FROM CPR LIMIT 100 . I need to make a function to pass that text as a string to sqldf in the way sqldf(text, dbname = secon_function_argument) and more procedures into that function. The SQL code can be very long. If we get this simple function, i will also use it to pass Rcpp code. All this is because i am passing SQL-php code into R-sqldf-rcpp code in the same file, for clarity.

Comment: So could you read in the file with something like `paste0(readLines("myfile"), collapse = " ")`? And then use that string as an argument to `sqldf`?

Comment: Yes, i could do that, but the file does not contain only SQL, etc. Anyway, if we do not find a way to quote any code/text in R, i will make myself the quotes for those pieces of text. So it is not that i can not proceed without that function, but having that function would be helpful and more efficient (also because quotes makes every thing appear the same in the text, and i like to keep the color formatting for clarity).

Comment: @MiguelVazq: It feels like you're describing the step you're stuck on, not the overall goal.  R is sometimes non-intuitive for people who are new to it, and it feels like you have a way in mind to achieve your goal, but that it's not very R-friendly, and so you're stuck on this step.  There's probably a better way altogether to achieve your goal, without this step, but we'll need more information about what you have in mind.  Perhaps a new question with all the details about your goal would be in order?

Comment: @Aaron: ok, i see your point. Before asking the question, i did not know if the answer was going to be an "evident" and simple one (as happens sometimes when we get stuck, as you know), or a difficult one (as it seems to be). There are other ways to do that (as I described), but it is less convenient for me. The goal is simple: i want to quote any code/text with a function. That is the goal. Reasons: the one i said before: not loosing formatting, more clarity, more efficiency (that function could do the quoting + other tasks in one single function name). I think those are reasons enough.

Comment: I think the question people are asking, though, is where do these statements come from? Are you typing them in manually at the console? Or are you reading them in from an external file of some kind? Answers to your problem are going to depend on what you're *actually* trying to do rather than the solution you're currently trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Thomas : yes, perhaps i did not explain myself enough. The code that i want to "quote" is into the same file. Not in any external file. In the SAME file, and my R code is there too. This is to get clarity and for other reasons it is needed. But i DO NOT aim for a solution for that very special case, but a general solution: how to quote a text in R with a function. Because other functions, etc., will use that too, etc. Of course, if there is no solution to this general question, i will take some more specific ones (and i have them already). thank you anyway. :-)

Comment: How are you loading that code into R? Copy-paste into the console? Or using `source`?

Comment: No source, no copy and paste. This is what i want to solve: I want to take as an argument in a function the text i want to pass to "string" to make sql statments in sqldf, and OTHER applications. So we should ONLY, ONLY focus on solving this: How to quote any piece of text (in the same file as the code) with a function. I am ONLY interested on solving that. I have solutions for other less generic questions. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Miguel, it seems pretty clear that this is impossible.  It also is still very unclear what your use case for this is.  There is most likely an R-friendly way of completing your task, but without more details, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like:

```
foo <- function(){
    readLines(n=1)
}
z <- foo()
SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 100
z
#[1] "SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 100"
```

But, it's hard to say without context.

Comment: Won't work with e.g. `foo( 1234 ERE 34e3 & )` but I don't see why the OP can't just wrap the expression in quotes?!

Comment: @SimonO101 Oh, I agree...that's why I asked for clarification above. My impression is it's not possible to do exactly what OP is asking for.

Comment: Yeah, mine too, but I'm waiting to see if someone knows how to do this (but I agree - I can't think *why* you'd need to do this!)

Comment: Yes, good points you have, but, i already step a few times in cases that i would need to do that. One example is to pass SQL code to string to use it with sqldf, other is to pass Rcpp code to string to make cxxfunctions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you type `foo( 1234 ERE 34e3 & )` at the R command line, then `1234 ERE 34e3 &` is evaluated before `foo` is called.  This means that it doesn't matter how you define `foo`, passing in things that aren't valid R code will always throw an error.

<del>You need to wrap the call to `foo` in `try` or `tryCatch` to deal with this.</del>

As Thomas points out in the comment, `1234 ERE 34e3 &` won't even parse correctly, never mind evaluate, so `try` is useless.

I suggest that you abandon this idea and do what everyone else does:
If you are typing code directly at the command line, then just type the extra `""` characters around it.  If your code is in a file, use `readLines` (or `scan` or whatever) to get the code as a string.

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. But for the reasons you state, though, I don't think `try`/`tryCatch` will help here because the contents of `foo(...)` will always fail to parse before they fail to evaluate.

Comment: So, isn´t there a way to pass arguments to foo without being evaluated before they get into the function?? I am aware of subsitute, expression, etc. but they do not do the trick...

Comment: @MiguelVazq: Your language here is a little fuzzy, and to do things like this it will help to use language more precisely; the problem is not with evaluation (and actually, arguments are not evaluated until used within the function) but they do have to parse.

Comment: Seems i will abandon the idea and quote or read those lines, as you say, until we find a better solution. Thanks for the fast and good answers.

Answer (score 2):

my few cents, function calls can't really handle spaces. So I'm not even sure can you do "SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 100", because of the space between. Otherwise this works

```
foo <- function(...){
  cl <- match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)
  cl <- paste(cl)[2]
  cl <- substr(cl, 6, nchar(cl)-1)
  cl
 }
 foo(FROMDATALIMIT)
 foo(x = 5)
 foo(x = 5+5)
 foo(from&data)
 foo(x = 5, FROMDATALIMIT)
 foo(from data limit) #doesn't work
```

Comment: I'd probably go with `deparse` rather than `paste`, since it makes the intention clearer.  Otherwise, nicely done.

Comment: @RichieCotton, I haven't actually used `deparse` in any of my scripts. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Good approach, but it does not work with for example:  LIMIT 10 FROM 23 . We need to find a way to pass all that without being evaluated.

Comment: @MiguelVazq , unfortunately I'm out of ideas. I tried adding `try` / `trycatch` with `geterrmessage` but that didn't work. The `geterrmessage` almost gives the complete result, but it ends to like for the second space. My solution works for every statement as long as it doesn't have a space in it.

Comment: @MiguelVazq, oh this is still going. I thought by now someone smarter would have answred. I'll give this another shot tomorrow maybe...